# How to set up a custom webdriver for splinter in python?

Tags: python, web-applications, selenium-firefoxdriver, splinter

I have read the api doc on how to setup the the chrome webdriver but I am a little new to **kwargs and I have to pass the executable_path as a dictionary entry, can some one tell me what am I doing wrong in my code?

```
executable_path = {'executable_path':'/usr/bing/firefox-esr'}
browser = Browser('firefox', **executable_path)
```

this is the error im getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logger.py", line 10, in <module>
    browser = Browser('firefox', **executable_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 63, in Browser
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
```

and this is the code that is supplied by the splinter website as an example

```
executable_path = {'executable_path':'</path/to/chrome>'}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm guys, the problem was I didn't have a geckodriver in usr/local/bin folder and then you can set browser = Browser ('firefox')

Answer (score 0):

You specified 'firefox' instead of 'chrome', and Splinter's firefox driver does not have the `executable_path` argument.

See the source for Splinter 0.7.4: https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/e23df9c7e0ba9d1b495292cf8c23c0fe4192b26d/splinter/driver/webdriver/firefox.py#L20

Comment: Yes but how do I make it so I can use Firefox-esr. Does splinter support Firefox-Esr webdrivers? Im running this on Kali linux by the way